# C#: Group subdirectories by their parent directory and sort by creation time to get the newest

Tags: c#, find, hierarchy, subdirectory, timespan

In my directory hierarchy, I do not know how deep each directory matches a name pattern (for example: "*_select"), so I look for all subdirectories with that specific pattern.

So, for a hierarchy like:

```
C:
└── Main
    ├── ABC
    │   └── a_select (creation: 01-Jan-1900)
    │   └── b_select (creation: 02-Jan-1900)
    └── DEF
        └── GHI
            └── c_select (creation: 01-Jan-1900)
```

I search for:

```csharp
List<string> patternDirs = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Main", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(subd => Regex.IsMatch(subd, @".+?_select$")).ToList();
```

Then, I go over the list, and for each subdirectory found, when 30 days have passed since each was created, I would like to delete the directory and all its contents.

```csharp
foreach (string subdir in patternDirs)
{
    var subdirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subdirInfo);
    DateTime subdirCreationTime = subdirInfo.CreationTime;
    bool pastTime = subdirCreationTime <= (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 00));
    
    if(pastTime)
    {
       // Delete...
    }
}
```

My issue is that in case *all* the subdirectories of a particular parent directory have passed, I would like *to keep the one that was created most recently* (in the shown example it will keep `b_select` and `c_select`).

To accomplish that, I believe I should sort all of the directories by their parent directory, then go over them sorted. What's the most efficient way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution (although it might not be the most efficient):

```cs
// Step #01:
// Create a dictionary where the key is the parent directory
// and the value is a list containing all of its directories.
IDictionary<string, List<DirectoryInfo>> patternsByParent = new Dictionary<string, List<DirectoryInfo>>();

// Step #02:
// Fill the dictionary
foreach (string pattern in patternDirs)
{
    string parent = Directory.GetParent(pattern).ToString();   // Key
    DirectoryInfo patternDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pattern); // Value

    // if the key exists already => just add
    if (patternsByParent.ContainsKey(parent))
    {
        patternsByParent[parent].Add(patternDirInfo);
    }
    // create an entire new key-value pair
    else
    {
        patternsByParent.Add(parent, new List<DirectoryInfo> { patternDirInfo });
    }
}

// Step #03:
// Go through the dictionary, order each List<DirectoryInfo> by 'Creation Time' 
// in ascending order
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DirectoryInfo>> entry in patternsByParent)
{
    List<DirectoryInfo> orderedAscendingList = entry.Value
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToList();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo pattern in orderedAscendingList)
    {
        // Do whatever...
    }
}
```